# Selectable, draggable and droppable items in jquery with middle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm working on an exercise to move from a list or another that allows:

1. Drag and drop from one list to the other items.
2. Select one or more items and press the "Select" button and pass them to the right list.
3. Select one or more items on the left to list and drag and drop in the right list.
   My problem is that I can not make points 2 and 3, gives me the ui.draggable and ui.droppable conflicts with ui.selectable. I do not know which may be the problem!

I was looking for other similar exercises here in stackoverflow but I can not fix it.

My code is:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f9zW/613/embed/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $listaI = $("#listaI"),
        $listaD = $("#listaD");

    // hacemos que los items de la galeria sean "draggable"
    $("li", $listaI).draggable({
        cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
        revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
        containment: "document",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move"
    });


    $("#listaI").selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var result = $("#select-result").empty();
            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
                var index = $("#listaI li").index(this);
                result.append("#listaD");

            });
        }
    });

    // a trash le asiganmos la interacción droppable
    $listaD.droppable({
        accept: "#listaI > li", //aceptando los ítems de la galería
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).find(".placehold").remove();
            if ($(this).find("li").length > 2) {
                alert("No se puede agregar más de tres alumnos");
                return false;
            }
            deleteImage(ui.draggable);
        }
    });


    // a gallery le asignamos la interacción droppable también, aceptando los items de trash
    $listaI.droppable({
        accept: "#listaD li",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            recycleImage(ui.draggable);
        }
    });

    function deleteImage($item) {
        $item.fadeOut(function() {
            var $list = $("ul", $listaD).length ?
                $("ul", $listaD) :
                $("<ul class='listaI ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo($listaD);
            $item.appendTo($list).fadeIn();
        });
    }

    function recycleImage($item) {
        $item.fadeOut(function() {
            $item
                .find("a.ui-icon-refresh")
                .remove()
                .end()
                .find("li")
                .end()
                .appendTo($listaI)
                .fadeIn();

            if ($("#listaD li").length == 0) {
                $("#listaD").append("<p class='placehold'>Please drag and drop items here.</p>")
            }

        });
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
ul,
ol,
li {
    list-style: none;
}
.widgetContain {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
h1.ui-widget-header {
    margin: 0px;
}
#listaD p {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
#listaIzquierda {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#listaI .ui-selecting {
    background: #FECA40;
}
#listaI .ui-selected {
    background: #F39814;
    color: white;
}
#listaIzquierda ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
li.ui-widget-content {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 2px auto;
}
#listaDerecha {
    float: left;
}
#listaD {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 300px;
}
#selecDiv {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
#selecBtn {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="listaIzquierda" class="widgetContain">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">List</h1>
    <ul id="listaI" class="listaI ui-helper-reset">
        <li class="ui-widget-content"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span> Item 1 </li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span> Item 2 </li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span> Item 3 </li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span> Item 4 </li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span> Item 5 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="widgetContain" id="selecDiv">
    <input type="submit" value="Seleccionar" name="seleccionarBtn" id="selecBtn">
</div>
<div id="listaDerecha" class="widgetContain">
    <div id="listaD">
        <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Selected</h1>
        <p class="placehold">Please drag and drop items here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If anyone can help me I will be very grateful. Thank you very much!
Regards!

Comment: check this link may will help you http://www.dotnetcurry.com/jquery/1066/move-items-multi-select-list-jquery

Comment: For DEMO : 
http://www.jquerycookbook.com/demos/S4-DropDownULLists/43-MoveMultiSelectListItems.html

Comment: Thank you @MannanBahelim this is the solution for the button but if I want to select multiple items and drag and drop them to another div as it should?

Comment: View Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/T68Fn/